# Cannot get values to store in SQLite Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, hashmap

So I have the following pieces of code and I can't seem to get my application to store any information in the SQLite Database, Any help will be appreciated! Below is my database handler.

```
        public void insertRec(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {
            SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("regNo", queryValues.get("regNo"));
            values.put("carMake", queryValues.get("carMake"));
            values.put("carModel", queryValues.get("carModel"));
            database.insert("recs", null, values);
            database.close();
        }
}
```

Here is the button code I use to add a new record.

```
 public class Record extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

        public void onClick(View view) {

            HashMap<String, String> queryValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
            queryValues.put("regNo", regNo.getText().toString());
            queryValues.put("carMake", carMake.getText().toString());
            queryValues.put("carModel", carModel.getText().toString());
            controller.insertRec(queryValues);
```

Comment: So what is the problem. You cant insert record ? or you cant get value from ContentValues

Comment: I can't seem to add a record. When I pull the database out into a sqlite viewer it shows my table etc but with no data in it.

Comment: Try to debug your app and get exception or error.

Comment: Nothing happens, no errors come up or anything like that.

Comment: Can not say from this piece of code. Can you provide your database controller code?

Comment: Its too long for the characters in the text box of stack overflow :(

Comment: Follow this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/ and check your code.